GraphicsView does not work in android .net maui release
I'm having a problem with GraphicsView on Android .net Maui when I install the APK on my cell phone or compile it in release in VS, when I enter the screen it doesn't load and the application crashes, follow the source
view
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>


<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="GymAPP.View.Treinos.TimerPage"
         xmlns:mopupsanim="clr-namespace:Mopups.Animations;assembly=Mopups"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Mopups.Pages;assembly=Mopups"            
         BackgroundColor="#80000000"
         CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="False"
         HasKeyboardOffset="False"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

<pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <mopupsanim:ScaleAnimation
        DurationIn="700"
        EasingIn="BounceOut"
        PositionIn="Center"
        PositionOut="Center"
        ScaleIn="1"
        ScaleOut="0.7" />
</pages:PopupPage.Animation>



<ScrollView HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Border WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"                
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
        </Border.StrokeShape>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto">

            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto" >
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
                        <ImageButton x:Name="ImgbackBtn"
                          Source="backarrow.png"
                          CornerRadius="5"
                          HeightRequest="40"
                          WidthRequest="40"
                          Padding="5"
                          HorizontalOptions="Start"
                          VerticalOptions="Start"
                          Clicked="TapBack_Tapped"/>    
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
                        <GraphicsView 
                          x:Name="ProgressView"  
                          Margin="5, 5, 5, 5"
                          HeightRequest="160"
                          WidthRequest="160"/>

                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label x:Name="ProgressButton"
                                Text=""
                                FontSize="35"
                                HeightRequest="50"
                                WidthRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="10"
                                TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
                            <Label TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}" Text="Seg" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                        <Grid  Margin="5, 5, 5, 5"  ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*">
                            <ImageButton HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource stlContactBtn}" x:Name="btnplay" IsEnabled="False"  Clicked="play_Clicked" Source="playdois.png"/>
                            <ImageButton HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource stlContactBtn}" x:Name="btnStop" Clicked="stop_Clicked" Source="stop.png"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>

            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

 </ScrollView>
 </pages:PopupPage>

Back
using GymAPP.Libraries.Util;
using Mopups.Pages;
using Mopups.Services;
using Plugin.Maui.Audio;
using System.Reflection;

namespace GymAPP.View.Treinos;

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]


public partial class TimerPage : PopupPage
{
   private readonly ProgressArc _progressArc;
   private double _progress;
   private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new();
   private bool _playagain;
   private double _Minimum = 0;
   private double _Maximum;
   private double _Minutos;
   public TimerPage(double minutos)
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     _Minutos = minutos;
     _Maximum = minutos;
     _progressArc = new ProgressArc();
   }

   protected override void OnAppearing()
   {
       base.OnAppearing();
       ProgressView.Drawable = _progressArc;
       _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
       _playagain = false;
       UpdateArc();
   }

   private async void UpdateArc()
   {
      TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_Minutos);

    if (!_playagain)
      span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_Minutos);
    else
    {
     btnplay.IsEnabled = false;
     btnStop.IsEnabled = true;
     span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_Minutos);
 }

 _progress = span.TotalSeconds;

 while (!_cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
 {


     ProgressButton.Text = $"{_progress}";

     var teste = _Maximum / _progress;
     _progressArc.Progress = _progress / _Maximum;

     ProgressView.Invalidate();

     if (_progress == _Minimum)
     {
         _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
         Finalizar();
         return;

     }

     if (_progress > _Minimum && _progress <= 6)
     {
         var audioPlayer = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(await 
         FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("beep.mp3"));
         audioPlayer.Play();
         audioPlayer.Volume = 100;
     }

     _progress--;
     await Task.Delay(1000);
 }
}

Private async void stop_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    btnplay.IsEnabled = true;
    btnStop.IsEnabled = false;
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    _playagain = false;
}


private async void play_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _Minutos = Convert.ToDouble(ProgressButton.Text);
    btnplay.IsEnabled = false;
    btnStop.IsEnabled = true;
    _playagain = true;
    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    UpdateArc();
}
private void Finalizar()
{

    TapBack_Tapped(null, null);
}

private void TapBack_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    MopupService.Instance.PopAsync();
}

protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
    {
        Finalizar();
    });

    return true;
 }

}

Config MauiProgram
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup;
using GymAPP.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Mopups.Hosting;
using Mopups.Interfaces;
using Mopups.Services;

namespace GymAPP;

 public static class MauiProgram
 {
   public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
   {
      var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
         .UseMauiApp<App>()
         .ConfigureMopups()
         .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            })
          .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
          .UseMauiCommunityToolkitMarkup()
          .UseMauiCommunityToolkitMediaElement();

      #if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
     #endif       
       return builder.Build();
  }
 }

Would there be any way to turn on log or compile the release in VS and understand the reason for the timer breaking?

you need to look at the logs and/or add some exception handling/logging to your app

Hi Jason, is there a source I can use? because on my cell phone I can't activate log and in debug mode it's normal, only in release mode does it crash

You can still use adb to view the logs.  And there are many crash reporting tools available

Olá Jason, era os StaticResource, removi e funcionou

Well, according to your reply, as answer:

I'm having a problem with GraphicsView on Android .net Maui when I install the APK on my cell phone or compile it in release in VS, when I enter the screen it doesn't load and the application crashes

It is caused by using StaticResource, such as this: TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}". Removing it can solve the problem.
